# Whether it is possible in Microsoft. Office. Interop. Outlook.userproperties to add an array

Tags: outlook, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin

Whether it is possible in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.UserProperties` to add an array/list of integer numbers and how? Usage of type `OlUserPropertyType.olEnumeration` leads to an exception at a stage of adding of the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no array support in the [MAPI-supported user properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208152%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You would have to serialize the array to a string - [`OlUserPropertyType.OlText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208152%28v=office.12%29.aspx) ([*`PT_STRING8`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920447%28v=office.12%29.aspx)) using some serialized array format (XML, CSV, JSON, etc.).